# Is there a way to start R without printing the R version ... message?

Tags: r

I am running `CMD ["R", "some_optoins"]` in a docker image, and I want to suppress the printing of the R start up message, like `R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)`, which is quite long and increases the log size.

Is there a command-line option to suppress that?

Comment: If you want to run in batch mode, consider `CMD ["Rscript", "some_options"]` as your Docker command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`R --help` from the command line shows

> -q, --quiet           Don't print startup message